# Spring Cache Abstraction with Hazelcast and time consuming method

Tags: spring, caching

How using the Spring Cache Abstraction handle the case, when I want to call method getNameTimeConsumingMethod but if the result is not in cache then I do not want to wait for execution this method and return the result method getNameIfNotInCache.

```
@Cacheable(value = "cacheName", key = "#key")
public String getNameTimeConsumingMethod(String key) {
//time consuming method
}


public String getNameIfNotInCache(String key) {
//fast method if cacheName does not have a key
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the key is in cache, getNameTimeConsumingMethod won't be executed, because the result will be returned from cache. 
If the key is not in cache, you want to execute getNameIfNotInCache.

What I conclude is, you don't want to execute anything inside getNameTimeConsumingMethod.
Then why don't you just call getNameIfNotInCache from getNameTimeConsumingMethod and return it?

Comment: If the key is not in cache I want return result from getNameIfNotInCache but I want the method getNameTimeConsumingMethod to be done in the background and result this method  added a new value to cache